# How does the kernel determine the next pid?

Tags: kernel, freebsd

I am trying to understand how the FreeBSD kernel allocates pids?

I found the [following code](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/kern/kern_fork.c?v=FREEBSD10;im=10#L184):

```
 186 static int randompid = 0;
 187 
 188 static int
 189 sysctl_kern_randompid(SYSCTL_HANDLER_ARGS)
 190 {
 191         int error, pid;
 192 
 193         error = sysctl_wire_old_buffer(req, sizeof(int));
 194         if (error != 0)
 195                 return(error);
 196         sx_xlock(&allproc_lock);
 197         pid = randompid;
 198         error = sysctl_handle_int(oidp, &pid, 0, req);
 199         if (error == 0 && req->newptr != NULL) {
 200                 if (pid < 0 || pid > pid_max - 100)     /* out of range */
 201                         pid = pid_max - 100;
 202                 else if (pid < 2)                       /* NOP */
 203                         pid = 0;
 204                 else if (pid < 100)                     /* Make it reasonable */
 205                         pid = 100;
 206                 randompid = pid;
 207         }
 208         sx_xunlock(&allproc_lock);
 209         return (error);
 210 }
 211 
 212 SYSCTL_PROC(_kern, OID_AUTO, randompid, CTLTYPE_INT|CTLFLAG_RW,
 213     0, 0, sysctl_kern_randompid, "I", "Random PID modulus");
 214 
 215 static int
 216 fork_findpid(int flags)
 217 {
 218         struct proc *p;
 219         int trypid;
 220         static int pidchecked = 0;
 221 
 222         /*
 223          * Requires allproc_lock in order to iterate over the list
 224          * of processes, and proctree_lock to access p_pgrp.
 225          */
 226         sx_assert(&allproc_lock, SX_LOCKED);
 227         sx_assert(&proctree_lock, SX_LOCKED);
 228 
 229         /*
 230          * Find an unused process ID.  We remember a range of unused IDs
 231          * ready to use (from lastpid+1 through pidchecked-1).
 232          *
 233          * If RFHIGHPID is set (used during system boot), do not allocate
 234          * low-numbered pids.
 235          */
 236         trypid = lastpid + 1;
 237         if (flags & RFHIGHPID) {
 238                 if (trypid < 10)
 239                         trypid = 10;
 240         } else {
 241                 if (randompid)
 242                         trypid += arc4random() % randompid;
 243         }
 244 retry:
 245         /*
 246          * If the process ID prototype has wrapped around,
 247          * restart somewhat above 0, as the low-numbered procs
 248          * tend to include daemons that don't exit.
 249          */
 250         if (trypid >= pid_max) {
 251                 trypid = trypid % pid_max;
 252                 if (trypid < 100)
 253                         trypid += 100;
 254                 pidchecked = 0;
 255         }
 256         if (trypid >= pidchecked) {
 257                 int doingzomb = 0;
 258 
 259                 pidchecked = PID_MAX;
 260                 /*
 261                  * Scan the active and zombie procs to check whether this pid
 262                  * is in use.  Remember the lowest pid that's greater
 263                  * than trypid, so we can avoid checking for a while.
 264                  */
 265                 p = LIST_FIRST(&allproc);
 266 again:
 267                 for (; p != NULL; p = LIST_NEXT(p, p_list)) {
 268                         while (p->p_pid == trypid ||
 269                             (p->p_pgrp != NULL &&
 270                             (p->p_pgrp->pg_id == trypid ||
 271                             (p->p_session != NULL &&
 272                             p->p_session->s_sid == trypid)))) {
 273                                 trypid++;
 274                                 if (trypid >= pidchecked)
 275                                         goto retry;
 276                         }
 277                         if (p->p_pid > trypid && pidchecked > p->p_pid)
 278                                 pidchecked = p->p_pid;
 279                         if (p->p_pgrp != NULL) {
 280                                 if (p->p_pgrp->pg_id > trypid &&
 281                                     pidchecked > p->p_pgrp->pg_id)
 282                                         pidchecked = p->p_pgrp->pg_id;
 283                                 if (p->p_session != NULL &&
 284                                     p->p_session->s_sid > trypid &&
 285                                     pidchecked > p->p_session->s_sid)
 286                                         pidchecked = p->p_session->s_sid;
 287                         }
 288                 }
 289                 if (!doingzomb) {
 290                         doingzomb = 1;
 291                         p = LIST_FIRST(&zombproc);
 292                         goto again;
 293                 }
 294   
 296         /*
 297          * RFHIGHPID does not mess with the lastpid counter during boot.
 298          */
 299         if (flags & RFHIGHPID)
 300                 pidchecked = 0;
 301         else
 302                 lastpid = trypid;
 303 
 304         return (trypid);
 305 }
 306
```

but I have a number of question:

1. What is RFHIGHPID used for?
2. Why is there randomness? Does this actually add security? Or is this just to help create fragmentation?
3. Where is randompid otherwise set?
4. Why does this code have to 'try' a pid? Is this code racy? What happens if more than one process tries to get a pid at the same time?
5. Is it possible to start a process with a specific pid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is there randomness? Does this actually add security? Or is this just to help create fragmentation?

Random PIDs do not add much security.  The point of random PIDs is to make it more likely that a PID will be available in the space which is chosen to reduce the chance of a conflict.

> Why does this code have to 'try' a pid? Is this code racy? What happens if more than one process tries to get a pid at the same time?

Look carefully, there is a lock around the entire thing.  The 'try' portion is when it scans the zombie list and other lists.

> Is it possible to start a process with a specific pid?

No.